# Typescript simple call back function

Tags: typescript, callback

In typescript what is the simplest way to make a function wait for a callback function within?

```
public isLoggedIn() : boolean
{
    myCallBackFunction.getItem(access_token).then((value) => {
        return value;
    });

}
```

This of course doesn't compile, but how do I make it wait for the result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: Not Ajax tried several but none work

Comment: The async concepts are the same whether it's ajax or any other async callback. Update your question with what you're trying that isn't working. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron.

Comment: How about a simple example.  Trying to keep to few lines

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid but there is no such way.

If the api you are using does not provide you with synchronous counterpart of asynchronous function (in your case its `getItem`), you are forced to use it in asynchronous way either by consuming promises directly or using async/await.